What is the usage of this に
句の包摂:
語の内部に句が包み込まれる
Gramatically speaking, is this に marking passive agent (wrapped by..) or location? (wrapped inside..), Both fit to me, so I have hard time deciding

Grammatically, Japanese is inherently ambiguous so both interpretations are possible, but when taking context into account, there is only one logical explanation left. Because に is preceded by 内部 "inside", it's a location, so it's only logical to view に as the location marker.

語の内部に句が包み込まれる 
Sentences are enclosed with languages. (Or literally, sentences are contained into the inside part of languages)

It's not logical to say 内部 is the action-performer. It's a location, so it can't do the 包み込む.
However, there can be cases where even the full sentence doesn't provide enough context and both explanations are still equally likely. In that case, you'd have to either guess or get more info about the situation.

社長に紹介されました.
Introduced to the 社長 by someone else?
Introduced by the 社長 to someone else?


Thank you for your answer. By the way, the 語 here means "a word/words".
